Upgrading Azure Function to dotnet 8 isolated breaks the EventGrid Trigger
After making the suggested upgrade to .NET 8 and isolated worker functions, my blob storage event grid webhook no longer fires.

You need to add new querystring parameters to your storage account event webhook subscription to authenticate properly:
?functionName=Host.Functions.YourFunctionName
&code=zzzzzzzxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyy==

You need to add the name of your function in the format "Host.Functions.YourFunctionName".
You need to add the blob extension key (code) which can be found in the Azure Portal for your function, under App Keys, called blobs_extension.
So the webhook should look something like this: https://<FUNCTION_APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/blobs?functionName=Host.Functions.BlobTriggerEventGrid&code=<BLOB_EXTENSION_KEY> 
Full reference can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-grid-blob-trigger?pivots=programming-language-csharp#build-the-endpoint-url

I probably need to start this as a new question or support case, but when I follow those instructions I can't create the webhook in Event Grid; it gives me an error indicating "Webhook validation handshake failed" and "Http POST request failed with response code Unknown".

Got it (in case anyone else gets stuck). Event Grid doesn't support outbound TLS 1.3 connections, which our Functions App was set to enforce
